# Нужно создать уникальную ссылку вида: "../message/ftr45e32fgv56d2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Почти решил задачу сам. Так как модели `Message` у меня поле `body` шифруется в `AES` я переписал метод `to_param` body - шифрофанный текст вида `wuTekBX7p0K+olP6Vd/8Jw==$okRXvvSB1ZRRuhxF3O9EIg==`.

```
def to_param
    "#{id}-#{body.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')[0..12].insert(3, self.id.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join).first).insert(9, self.id.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join).last).parameterize}"
end
```

Да смотрится немного странно:)

В конечном итоге ссылка получается `/messages/2-wut2ekbx72p0kol`
Но нужно сделать без `id` в начале и чтобы была уникальной.

Comment: как мне кажется, лучше всего использовать для этого средства БД - создать линковочную таблицу между идентификаторами и ссылками, а ссылки генерировать с использованием GUID при вставке в таблицу нового `id`.

Comment: @Alex Chermenin c GUID вариант неплохой, немного символов многовато будет (мне бы до 16), но все же может подойти. Значит нужно создать таблицу соответствий GUID код - id. И потом через нее доставать объект. Сложновато, но как вариант сгодится.

Comment: @Alex Chermenin как реагировать на вставку нового объекта с id в таблицу messages? Пробовал через after_save/after_create не получается,  message еще не имеет id на тот момент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед созданием записи в таблицу messages генерируй нужный код, его пиши в отдельное поле в таблице, например link_id. По нему как раз будешь проверять уникальность. Естественно, на него нужен индекс.

```
  before_create :generate_link_id

  def generate_link_id
    self.link_id = SecureRandom.hex(10)
    self.link_id = SecureRandom.hex(10) while Message.find_by_link_id(self.link_id)
  end
```

route будет соответственно

```
get "/message/:link_id" => "messages#show"
```

По нему и будешь искать message в контроллере.

```
def show
  @message = Message.find_by_link_id! params[:link_id]
end
```

Пытаться изобразить что-то из шифрованного body - так себе затея. В теории можно, конечно, придумать некоторую уникальную hash-функцию, но зачем?